# Magento 2 data migration error ConfigurablePrices step mismatch of entities

Tags: magento2, magento2-migration-tool

I'm migrating data from M1 v1.9.3.2 to M2 v2.1.5, and receiving this error at the volume check for ConfigurablePrices:

```
[2017-04-03 19:16:34][INFO][mode: data][stage: volume check][step: ConfigurablePrices step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: 1 sec 
[2017-04-03 19:16:34][ERROR]: Mismatch of entities in the document: catalog_product_entity_decimal
```

The mismatch is due to 3 records being added to the M2 `catalog_product_entity_decimal` table that aren't in the M1 table.

I don't understand where this is coming from. I've done a few migrations and the only times I've run into something like this is when versions of the sites, the migration tool, and migration maps don't match.

I am certain I am using v2.1.5 of the tool to match the M2 site, and I am using v1.9.3.2 config and mappings to match M1.

I have run and rerun this into a fresh M2 DB, reloaded the M1 DB, etc., but nothing gets me past this error.

Any thoughts??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several hours digging through the migration routines and the database, I found the error.

The three products that were being added to the catalog_product_entity_decimal table also appeared to be duplicated products sharing the same SKUs with their original products. Magento won't allow saving a product with a non-unique ski, so it was evident once I tried to resale a product what the issue was.

The three dupe products also belonged to a different attribute set, so if I searched in the product admin by attribute set, I'd see the sku in the grid. If I searched by product name in the admin (and also searched the product in the database), the dupe products would have a null SKU. If I entered the product edit screen in the admin with an apparent null sku in the grid, the sku attribute field would populate with a duplicate sku.

Once I set the dupe product names and SKUs to something unique and re-saved the products, the error was gone.

Happy migrating!